# Removing the Label From Django's TextArea Widget

Tags: python, django, textarea, label, widget

How do I remove the label that comes attached to the TextArea I am trying to use with Django? I'm trying to find ANY information about this issue but I cannot seem to find anything relating to my problem. This is what I'm doing in my code:

```
class CommentForm(forms.Form):
    comment = forms.CharField(widget=forms.Textarea())
```

This is the HTML that it produces:

```
<label for="id_text">Text:</label> 
<textarea id="id_text" rows="10" cols="40" name="text"></textarea>
```

That label is no good and I'd like a way to remove it. That code was produced via:

```
{{ form.as_p }}
```

(I removed the paragraph tags because they are irrelevant)

EDIT: I added the class CommentForm part for further clarification.

Anyone have any suggestions?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The [Django documentation on customizing labels](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/forms/api/#ref-forms-api-configuring-label) says it could be turned off with `auto_id` argument to Form constructor:

```
f = ContactForm(auto_id=False)
```

Comment: nvm my previous comment, I deleted it, however this still does nothing for me, am I possibly initializing it in the wrong spot? I'm doing it in the view before the page is rendered.

Comment: I am not really sure but I guess you could put it like this:

class CommentForm(forms.Form):
    auto_id = False 
    comment = forms.CharField(widget=forms.Textarea())

Comment: Ok, it looks like this SHOULD be the way to do it, however I'm getting no change. I'll update the question with more results.

Comment: It did. The label is gone. However, the text part of the label was really what I wanted to remove. Nevertheless, this is the correct answer to my stated question.

Answer (score 36):

This should work with the latest version (trunk) of django:

```
comment = forms.CharField(label="", help_text="", widget=forms.Textarea())
```

Hope that helps!

Comment: Unfortunately I'm using Django 1.0.2, and I guess this doesn't happen to work yet.

Comment: That's weird. It should not be a Django 1.1 feature (I just couldn't easily verify that it works in Django 1.0.2).

Comment: `<label>` is still there, just empty. (warning: kludge incoming) to hide it completely, i also [added a css file to my ModelAdmin](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/contrib/admin/#modeladmin-asset-definitions) which includes `label:empty { display: none; }`

Answer (score 4):

Try this in your form:

```
def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
    self.fields['comment'].label = ''
```

But for newer versions of django i prefer Iemonad's answer

Answer (score 2):

Not sure about old Django but u can now empty the form field labels in Meta for the new Django

```
class CustomForm(forms.Form):
    class Meta:
        ...  #other properties such as model, fields, widgets and help text
        labels = {
           'comment' : '',
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

A quick-and-dirty solution would be to iterate through the form manualy (with {% for field in form %}) and handle the "problematic" field specially. You could also override the as_p/as_table methods if needed.

Answer (score 0):

here is  another solution that had worked for me
with this

{% for field in form %} {{field.errors}} {% endfor %}

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).